# why mailto not work in mobile https page

Tags: html, mobile, https, mailto

I want to call the email client in the mobile web page. The followed code:

```html
<a href="mailto:88888@gmail.com">88888@gmail.com</a>
```

It works in the http page on mobile phone web page, but not works in the https web page?

Answer (score 0):

Use `target="_top"`,

```html
<a target="_top" href="mailto:88888@gmail.com">88888@gmail.com</a>
```